# Differential tensorial operator of the Ricci scalar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I was wondering if you could assist me in a problem I am having. I am working with $f(G)$ class gravity models and I am trying to derive the results from varying the action with respect to the $0-0$ and $i-i$ components.

Part of the equations of motion requires work with the differential tensorial operator defined as:

$D_{\mu \nu} \equiv g_{\mu \nu} \square - \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu}$,

and

$\square \equiv g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu}$.

I am required to perform a differential tensorial on the Ricci scalar. Would I be correct in stating that

$D_{\mu \nu} R \equiv 0$  ?

In this instance the Ricci scalar is varying only in time $t$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is only zero when the same indices are used.

Technically speaking I should have left the $\square \equiv g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\nu}$ as free indices i.e. I should have used $\square \equiv g^{\mu' \nu'} \nabla_{\mu''} \nabla_{\nu''}$

Thus before we get the answer we have to take a sum over all the coordinates in the coordinate system considered.